# Is there a way to insert a click event in a specific header table, retrieved from an array using *ngFor in Angular?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, click, ngfor

I have this array, which contains the headers table.

```js
header=['Ticket ID','Title','Date','Category','Read']
```

I use this array to popolate headers in table like this

```html
<tr><th *ngFor="let title of header" scope="col">{{ title }}</th></tr>
```

I want to add an event click only in Ticket ID header and Date header. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way, just filter events:

```
<tr>
  <th *ngFor="let title of header" scope="col" (click)="handleHeaderClick(title)>
    {{ title }}
  </th>
</tr> 


public handleHeaderClick(title: string): void {
  if (title === 'Ticket ID' || title === 'Date') {
    // your code for these types of column
  }
}
```